# Appendix heading suddenly becomes Chapter

Tags: appendices

I have a couple of appendices all with multiple tables. The first two appendices are labeled "Appendix A" and Appendix B".  At some point, tables in appendix B change their name to "Table 2.1"  instead of "Table B.#".  Then the next appendix is labeled "Chapter 3"

The document reads as follows

```
\include{Chapter1}

\include{Chapter2}

\appendix

\include{appendix1}

\include{appendix2}

\include{appendix3}

\include{appendix4}
```

What can be causing this?

Comment: clearly, something in appendix B

Comment: How should we know with that little code? Please give a compilable code and narrow down the actual problem. Delete everything not needed to show the behaviour you describe. If you can't find the culprit line of code then, you may post your MWE here and we are happy to help you. Thanks.

Comment: This is a crosspost to [LateX Community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=89865#p89865).

Comment: Appendices ARE chapters.  What you need is    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}

Comment: But @john, isn't that what appendix does? Woudn't cause a change in the second chapter either :-)

Comment: copy the file `appendix2` to some other name, and process that file by itself, making sure that it is preceded by all your packages, the command `\appendix`, and `\setcounter{chapter}{1}.  remove everything before the last known place where the "b" designation appears in the output.  then remove chunks of "ordinary" text (i.e., with no commands) between that and where "2" appears instead of "b".  examine what's left carefully.  the source of the problem should make itself obvious, but if not, you have a small enough example to post.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks for the suggestion. I deleted some tables from appendix 2 and it is now "working" , nonetheless there is no apparent reason for which the deleted tables should be causing this problem.When I place the file "appendix2" in the chapter sections, it does not cause any trouble with numbering subsequent chapters, only when it is in the appendix.

Comment: you might concoct a small example file that contains one "appendix" labeled element followed by maybe one sentence, and finish up with just enough of the offending table to produce a numbered output.  with that evidence (and an immediately-compilable example), someone here ought to be able to spot the culprit pretty quickly.  (sometimes the author "sees" what s/he expects to see, and needs another pair of eyes.  happens to me too.)